# Meaning of ICMPv6 packets?

Tags: networking, embedded, wireshark, dhcp

I'm struggling to get an embedded platform with fairly standard IPV4 networking running. I have a working prototype which obtains an IP via DHCP without problem on a point to point connection (single cat5 cable) attached to a test laptop.

On my new hardware I get the link up but no DHCP request gets to the server (monitoring with wireshark). However what I do see, 100% repeatable, when those packets should be received, is a couple of ICMPv6 packets from the test laptop. This happens every time, there is no other activity on that link at any other time.

It seems to me that those packets are trying to tell me something, but what? Perhaps the DHCP request is going out but malformed for some reason?
(I can't post the actual packet from my phone, will make a copy and do so later.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be something generated by the laptop when it sees the link comes up. Turned out to be unrelated to the issue I had (which was hardware related).